# Prevent duplicating Terraform resource during Terraform apply

Tags: azure, terraform

I have a solution to deploy an enterprise application into Azure using the cloud. I have modularized the solution into different modules as recommended by Terraform.

Link: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/modules/develop/composition

The problem arises from a single module responsible for creating the resource group, acting as the parent for the other modules. Each time this module is called by the child modules during Terraform apply, the resource group is duplicated.
I have attached screenshot for further references.
How can I prevent this?

**This is my Project folder structure**

[image]

**Terraform Plan output**
[image]

**This is how I define output variables.**
[image]

**This is how I used output vars in other modules.**
[image]

Comment: Can you confirm all the names are exactly the same? The screenshot does not show the whole name because the name gets shortened.

Comment: yes names are same. I have updated the screenshot as wel

Comment: Then you need a way of adding something random (or something predefined) to the name of the resource group, which you can do in the code.

Comment: no. this is define only one place under main.tf in recourse group module. this is exactly my question.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to known how exactly you defined your modules and their resources but it seems that you are calling your resource group module from each one of the other modules. This is necessary just if you want that the resources from each module have their own resource groups (and in this case you will need to pass different names for each one), but it seems that you want a unique resource group for the entire solution, isn't it?

In this case you need to:

- export an **output** in the **resource group module** (e.g. rg_name or any other name you want)
- in your **other modules** you must declare and define a required **variable** for the resource_group_name attribute (e.g. var.resource_group_name)
- in your **root module** (possible the main.tf file below the .gitignore file) in the call for each module you need to pass a **reference for your output** as the variable value (e.g. "resource_group_name = module.resource_group.rg_name")

Comment: Hi Daniel I'm doing exactly what you say in point 1& 2 . But not clear point 3. I just use all the module in root level main. tf  .  like below code snippet                                                                        
 module "networking" {
  source = "./modules/networking"
}    ........

Comment: Yes, it's correct. You have to use this for each module, but you need to pass the variable resource_group_name = module.resource_group.rg_name (except in the call for the resource group module obviously).. This way each module will will use the resource group name from your output.

Comment: I used the resource_group_name but it must be the variable name that you've defined inside your modules (in my example I would have resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name)

Comment: Hi Daniel. yes. I'm using variable approach. But without been module import we cannot use variable. its giving error module during terraforms plan. I have attached another screenshot showing how i defined variables for that resourse group. Thanks